# Is any way to get HP servers Errors Remotely without iLo GUI?

Tags: server, hardware

I have more than 200 HP servers in my company branches and I want to automatically monitor server hardware errors. I can see all servers in my WAN.
I want to write a program to monitor HP servers remotely. My application must call an API or other functions remotely, and then get results from servers. After that I can send error signal to my administrators if needed, and my alarm system can read this information and etc. Is any API (or HP Proliant facilities) to get hardware errors and warnings remotely? 
The Errors I want to monitor are:

1. Raid disk errors
2. Power Errors
3. CPU Fan Errors

I cant see more than 200 servers iLo GUI every day to monitor errors.

Comment: find a suitable tool and learn how to use it; there is plenty of commercial and free tools that can remotely monitor a computer. in the long run you will find it cheaper and more robust than a custom tool/script/whatever.

Comment: Yes, I can do it. but I want to use my programming skill first.

Comment: then provide some information about your skills and where you are with the development because as you wrote it the question is too broad to be answered. what's the language? what about the api you are talking about? you are just looking for them or you have any info about?

Comment: I am a good C++ and C# programmer. But I don't have any information about APIs (or other things) I can use.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to monitor iLO via API. You should be able to integrate your application to the iLO RESTful API. there are some monitoring examples available on [GitHub Python library](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/python-ilorest-library).

you can get things like rest/v1/Managers/{item}/ActiveHealthSystem you might want to look into the complete [data model](http://h22208.www2.hpe.com/eginfolib/servers/docs/HPRestfultool/iLo4/data_model_reference.html).

Ana
HPE Employee